# Hashkey and Distribution key in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Anyone can help to find the Hash Key and Distribution Key of a table in Oracle Sql Developer. A sql query.
We tried using dba_tab_partitions and all_tab_partitions. But we are not sure if it’s correct. Can someone please help with it?

Comment: Are you talking about the hash key for a cluster or something else? What do you think a distribution key is because that is not common terminology and it is unclear what you may be talking about? Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the relevant `CREATE` statements for your database objects (tables, etc); **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; and the expected output for your setup.

Comment: check out `dba_part_key_columns` / `dba_subpart_key_columns`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.